# How do two or more std::threads operate on the same function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I am developing a C++ program in which I am processing several pairs of data(arrays and matrices). Due to time requirements, I need to process corresponding pairs in parallel and I am planning to use std::threads for that purpose. Since they will be calling the same function, I need to make sure that they never mess with each others' operations.

I would like to know whether each thread creates its own call stack and local function variables for the same function called by different threads are unique to the caller.

Also, all the threads need to write to different parts of the same output array. Will it cause a problem even if they are not writing to the same portion of the array?

Comment: Each thread is separate, and will have their own stack. Unless they use global variables or other shared data they wont affect each other

Comment: I'd use `openmp` for that..

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I also think of using openmp since it is a basic parallelization and using c++ threads adds a little bit time overhead as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fine.

Each thread has its own stack and when two threads write to or read from different memory locations, there are no race conditions.

Potential pitfalls in your case would be:

- Your function writes to global variables.
- Your function gets parameters by reference and mutates them.
- There are locations in your output array that are accessed by both threads.

As a side note, if parallelization is that simple, it can be interesting to take a look at OpenMP or stuff like that that makes that kind of parallelization fairly simple.

Comment: Could tell whether openmp or c++ threads are more time efficient, since I am working on improving the execution time.

Comment: I'm not using OpenMP a lot, but I've heard that it is quite efficient. Depending on the characteristics of your problem, in particular the costs of your function, you may would have to put some work into your own `std::thread` based code to match (or outperform) OpenMP for your particular problem. And I think that there isn't a lot to gain by not using it in your situation.

Comment: I tried both std::thread and OpenMP to parallelize, for most of the cases their execution performance are neck and neck, while OpenMP is slightly better. For particular cases when threads are running at full performance (system monitor shows 100% CPU usage at all cores) std::thread falls way behind OpenMP, for some reason that I cannot figure out. OpenMP fits better to my needs than C++ threads.

Comment: @AliKavis The reason might be that you are creating too many threads, but again, OpenMP is simpler. If you do not see a reason to use `std::thread`, stick with OpenMP.